# Twitter API with JavaScript: delete tweet

Tags: javascript, meteor, twitter

I’m currently building an meteor app which should make use of the twitter API. Therefor I’m using the `mrt:twit` meteor package (https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/twit).

I have created an app at https://apps.twitter.com with my twitter account and I’m using my consumer_key, consumer_secret, oauth_access_token and oauth_access_token_secret within the meteor app.

What is working: I can query tweets and access all data available. I can also post tweets.

Whats not working: I cannot delete a tweet. I get this message:

```
 { [Error: Your credentials do not allow access to this resource]
   message: 'Your credentials do not allow access to this resource',
   statusCode: 403,
   code: 220,
   allErrors:
   [ { message: 'Your credentials do not allow access to this resource',
       code: 220 } ],
   twitterReply: '{"errors":[{"message":"Your credentials do not allow access to this resource","code":220}]}' }
```

My code looks like this:

```
'deleteSingleTweet': function(tweet_id) {

        Twit = new TwitMaker({
            consumer_key: consumer_key,
            consumer_secret: consumer_secret,
            access_token: oauth_access_token,
            access_token_secret: oauth_access_token_secret
        });

        const DeleteSingleTweetPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            Twit.get(`statuses/destroy/${tweet_id}`, function(err, data, response) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(data);
                }
            });
        });

        DeleteSingleTweetPromise
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

Has anybody an idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I paused the small project also and didn’t invest much more time. In the meantime the twitter API changes also. I‘m not sure if this works after all. I guess Twitter doesn‘t want that this works anyway.

Comment: I did not see it in the documentation.

Comment: I think the only problem you have here is that you are using `Twit.get()` when it should be a `post`.